# Postfix ignoring pcre login maps for sender

Tags: postfix

I am trying to figure out, why my postfix is ignoring my login maps completely without any errors in the log files.

Return of command postconf -m displays that pcre is supported.

```
btree
cidr
environ
fail
hash
internal
memcache
nis
pcre
proxy
regexp
sdbm
sqlite
static
tcp
texthash
unix
```

This is the contents of my main.cf

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
   reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
   reject_non_fqdn_sender,
   reject_unlisted_recipient
   permit_mynetworks,
   permit_sasl_authenticated,
   reject_unverified_sender,
   reject_unauth_destination,
   reject_sender_login_mismatch,
   reject_invalid_hostname,
   reject_unknown_sender_domain,
   reject_unknown_recipient_domain
   reject_rbl_client sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org,
   reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
   reject_rbl_client list.dsbl.org,
   reject_rbl_client rbl.mail-abuse.org,
   reject_rbl_client spamsources.fabel.dk

smtpd_sender_login_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/login_maps.pcre
```

login_maps.pcre contents:

```
/^(.*)@mydomain.com.br$/   ${1}
```

So i am authenticating as luciano@mydomain.com.br, but i am able to change my sender email for everything@mydomain.com.br and the e-mail is accepted.

What i am doing wrong or how is the syntax for preventing this?

Comment: what is the result of `postmap -q user@domain.com pcre:/etc/postfix/login_maps.pcre` ?

Comment: add to `smtpd_sender_restrictions`   `reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch`

Comment: Was  `reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch` necessary for pcre to work?

Comment: No it is not necessary, pcre is working very fine without it! There is a lot of famous mail servers in Brazil with this issue and everybody says that is a smtp protocol fail without any solution. But here is solved thanks to the tarleb pcre solution...

Comment: Cool, we are learning along with you too.

Comment: This option is mandatory: reject_sender_login_mismatch. Maybe the same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42224/discussion-between-luciano-andress-martini-and-rui-f-ribeiro).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` parameters are mixed with `smtpd_sender_restrictions` parameters.  Put any parameter that contains the word `sender` below `smtpd_sender_restrictions` and you should be golden:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
    reject_unlisted_recipient
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_unverified_sender,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    reject_invalid_hostname,
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain
    reject_rbl_client sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org,
    reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
    reject_rbl_client list.dsbl.org,
    reject_rbl_client rbl.mail-abuse.org,
    reject_rbl_client spamsources.fabel.dk

smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain,
    reject_sender_login_mismatch
```

You should also backlash-escape any literal dots `.` in the sender map regexp, those are special chars matching *ANY* character if not escaped.

```
/^(.*)@mydomain\.com\.br$/   ${1}
```

Comment: Its working like a charm now! Thank you so much!